# Create complex string from another string

Tags: php, string

I have the following string:

```
$string = "a/b/c/d/e/f/g";
```

I want to create another string with the following structure:

```
$return = "a|a/b|a/b/c|a/b/c/d|a/b/c/d/e|a/b/c/d/e/f|a/b/c/d/e/f/g";
```

I tried to create an array from the first string and use two loop but it is not working.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: `I tried to create an array from the first string and use two loop but it is not working.` What happens? Error, wrong results, other? Add the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one simple way to achieve what you want.

```
 <?php
   $string = "a/b/c/d/e/f/g";
   $temp = explode("/",$string);
   $allstr = [];
   $tempstr = [];
   foreach($temp as $t){
     $tempstr[] = $t ;
     $allstr[] = implode("/",$tempstr);
   }
   echo implode("|",$allstr);
 ?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/752465

Output

```
 a|a/b|a/b/c|a/b/c/d|a/b/c/d/e|a/b/c/d/e/f|a/b/c/d/e/f/g
```